# Doctrine2 Multiple level single table inheritance ( Unknown column )

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, single-table-inheritance

I am not sure if this is a bug or something wrong in my code:

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "customer" = "Customer", 
 *      "projectManager" = "ProjectManager", 
 *      "developer" = "Developer"
 * })
 */
abstract class Person
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Customer extends Person
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
abstract class Employee extends Person
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @Column(name="retired", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $retired;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class ProjectManager extends Employee
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Developer extends Employee
{
    // ...
}
```

When trying to update the database `app/console doctrine:schema:update --force` Doctrine ignores Employee::retired attribute and the application would result in error: Unknown column 'retired'

If I created the column manually everything is working as expected. Moreover, this only happens with single table so if I switch to class table inheritance then the column is created on schema update.

Comment: i archive the same problem mapping the Employee not abstract and mapped it in in the discriminatormap.

Comment: yeah I did that already and it works but I that was not needed with a class table inheritance, so maybe it is a bug!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot 'jump' to lowest level inheritance, you have to describe each level.

At leat it works with `@InheritanceType("JOINED")`, I *guess* it is the same with `SINGLE_TABLE`.

```
<?php
namespace MyProject\Model;

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "customer"       = "Customer", 
 *      "employee"       = "Employee",
 *      "projectManager" = "ProjectManager", 
 *      "developer"      = "Developer"
 * })
 */
abstract class Person
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Customer extends Person
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 * @InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @DiscriminatorColumn(name="discr", type="string")
 * @DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "employee"       = "Employee", 
 *      "projectManager" = "ProjectManager", 
 *      "developer"      = "Developer"
 * })
 */
abstract class Employee extends Person
{
    /**
     * @var boolean
     * @Column(name="retired", type="boolean", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $retired;
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class ProjectManager extends Employee
{
    // ...
}

/**
 * @Entity
 */
class Developer extends Employee
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I do not think you can modify DiscriminatorMap for a nested entity

Comment: My bad, I looked again at my own project and I saw that you have to put all the children *AND* sub-children in the DiscriminatorMap of the root parent. See my edit above.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to map your in-between abstract entities in the discriminator map of your root entity for this to work. Just do not make it an `@Entity`, but an `@MappedSuperclass`.

In your case `Employee` should be a `@MappedSuperclass` and everything *extending* `Employee` an `@Entity` represented in the map.